# Database imports for Mysql running on RDS is painfully slow

Tags: mysql, performance, import, amazon-rds

I have a db.t3.large running MYSQL in RDS with 8 GB ram and 40 GB storage. When I import a 300MB database into the RDS instance it takes 30 minutes. This doesn't look right to me. I have encryptions enabled and this instance uses gp2 not provisioned IOPS. What could be the possible issues here?

Comment: How was the import done?  What is the schema?  How big are the rows?  What indexes do you have?  And is this a dup?

Comment: Import is done via command line from a .sql file. Rows are quite ordinary, there are no very long rows. This is a dump from a similar database.
I have created a similar RDS instance with encryption turned off. The imports are significantly faster now. So it should be encryption I think.

Comment: Using `mysql <dump.sql`?  Or `source`?  Or `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?  Something else?

Comment: Using mysql <dump.sql

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the largest table.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I have made here was that I only provisioned 40 Gb of storage. It is recommended to provision at least 100GB of SSD or else there will be impact on exhaustion of initial IO credit balance.

I have increased the storage from 40 to a 100 GB and the time to import sql dump dropped from 30 minutes to 4 minutes. I should have read the warning from AWS when I created the instance.

[image: AWS warning]

Thanks Rick James for offering help.